# How to set camel sftp component file to done or failed depending on all the child route processing

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to implement different routes with the combination of sftp and file components as below

- Copying file from Sftp (**sftp://user:pwd@source-host:port**) to a file component path inside server (**file://incoming**)
- Read the file from file component (**file://incoming**) enrich data and send to a destination sftp (**sftp://user:pwd@destination-host:port**)

I want to mark / move the file  to **/done** folder in the source sftp only if processed successfully in the above steps.

I want to mark / move to the **/failed** folder in the source sftp only if it fails in any of the above steps. How to achieve this?

It is marking as done / failed as soon as it moves the file from sftp to local file system.